VS Code ставит закрывающий тег при копировании внутри HTML-файлов
Прошу помощи, ибо задолбала следующая проблема: при копировании VS Code ставит закрывающий тег там, где он не нужен. Например, есть кусочек кода:
<div>
    <form>
      <input/>
      <button></button>
    </form>
</div>

Но при копировании редактор вставляет вот ЭТО
<div></div>
    <form>
      <input/>
      <button></button>
    </form>
</div>

Из плагинов имеется:

All Autocomplete
Auto Complete Tag
Auto Close Tag
Auto Rename Tag
Auto Import
Impor Cost
JavaScript (ES6) code snippets
Live Sass Compiler
Live Server
Multiple clipboards for VSCode
Prettier - Code formatter
Sass (.sass only)
vscode-icons

Пробовал отключать все плагины – всё тоже самое.

Это не из-за плагинов. Это после обновления программы. Можно отключить автозакрытие тегов.
Для этого перейдите в настройки, по поиску найдите HTML: Auto Closing Tags, и уберите галочку. Мне помогло.

Огромное Вам спасибо) Думал, с ума сойду)
